# A gift on condition that I could take it back

Tags: marriage, bava-metzia, maseches-kiddushin

The Gemara in Kiddushin 6b says that one may not marry a woman with money given on condition that she return it afterwards, as it's like chalipin which is invalid for marriage.

Say that a man gives a woman money on condition that he has the right that if he wants to at some point in the future he has the ability to take it back. Would that be any different? On the one hand, at least for the foreseeable future, it remains the woman's. On the other hand, since the man has the right to take it back, perhaps it's the same as the Gemara's case.

What about a case where the man gives it to the woman on condition that it has the din of Nichsei Melug - he has the rights to use it and that which comes out of it, but it principally belongs to her. Since he gets some rights to it, is it the same as the Gemara's case? Or perhaps since he doesn't own the principle it would work? Is the machlokes about kinyan peiros k'kinyan haguf dami (BM 96a) applicable?

Comment: see mishna Nedarim 5, 6 אמרו חכמים, כל מתנה שאינה שאם הקדישה תהא מוקדשת, אינה מתנה.